# Don't read sharedPreferences from another class

Tags: android, class, preferences, shared

I'm trying to get my app to look first if shared preferences is set. If not it must open a page where you type them in, and then hopefully save them which I will use later. It looks like it either finds some shared preferences or my code is wrong because the main activity opens (the else statement executes).

Here is my Mainactivity:

```
        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    boolean check = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("Check",false);
    if(check){
        //Intent intent;
        Intent SharedPrefsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SharedPrefs.class);
        startActivity(SharedPrefsIntent); }
    else {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView brands = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.brands);
```

And here is the SharedPrefs:

```
        public class SharedPrefs extends MainActivity {
//public static Context context;
EditText ed1,ed2,ed3;
Button b1;

public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
public static final String Name = "nameKey";
public static final String Phone = "phoneKey";
public static final String Email = "emailKey";

SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.shared_prefs);

    ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    ed2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    ed3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);

    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String n  = ed1.getText().toString();
            String ph  = ed2.getText().toString();
            String e  = ed3.getText().toString();

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

            editor.putString(Name, n);
            editor.putString(Phone, ph);
            editor.putString(Email, e);
            editor.commit();
            Toast.makeText(SharedPrefs.this,"Thanks",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
      }

     }
```

I must be honest I'm not quite sure where I want Java to look for Shared preferences, "this makes the app run at least.

Comment: `boolean check = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("Check",false);`. You try to read that value. But where did you write it?

Comment: Replace this line 

 sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

by 
 sharedpreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

And very first getBoolean() call will return false. so update your conditional statements accordingly

Comment: Ok, thank you Napolean. I changed the getSharedPreferences to your suggestion and it works. I also changed the if statement of the  getBoolean to if(!check) and now it goes to the SharedPrefs class. Great. I then put and intent under the submit button to go to the MainActivity class if I submit, but then it throws it back to the SharedPrefs class. Shouldn't it then read that there is now Shared Preferences and go to the MainActivity class?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `SharedPrefs{}` class, declare the variable

```
public static boolean CHECK_VALUE = false;
```

In the same class inside `onClick(View v)` method after `editor.commit();`, set

```
CHECK_VALUE = true;
```

And in `MainActivity{}` class inside `OnCreate()` method

```
if(!SharedPrefs.CHECK_VALUE){
    //SharedPreferences was not used before
    Intent SharedPrefsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SharedPrefs.class);
    startActivity(SharedPrefsIntent);
  }
else {
//SharedPreference are already set
//Do your stuffs
}
```

**Actually you don't need a SharedPreference to check here. If you really do, then put**

```
editor.putBoolean("check", true);
```

inside`OnClick()` method of `SharedPrefs{}` class and to get it from or to use it in `MainActivity`

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SharedPrefs.MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Boolean Check = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("check", false);
if(!check){
  //SharedPreferences was not used before
  Intent SharedPrefsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SharedPrefs.class);
  startActivity(SharedPrefsIntent);
}
 else {
   //SharedPreference are already set
   //Do your stuffs
}
```